# Get text between tags using regex from HTML mail

Tags: javascript, regex

I came across a HTML mail format where some text is present between `"<![if !supportLists]>" and "<![endif]>"` tags. I want to extract the text between these tags using regular expression. Here is a sample text format 
Input: 
    `"<![if !supportLists]><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>Index<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'> Value &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span><![endif]>"`

Expected Output: `"Index Value &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"`

Comment: as you just changed your question, and i already answered it. Down voting you. Please be specific at the very front whenever you ask question

Comment: Please don't use regex for HTML. Why not use JS/jQuery? `$('#someDiv').text()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that but I am new on stackoverflow and was not sure how to escape tags in editor

Comment: try this - `>([\s\w&;]+)<` Demo [here](https://regexr.com/3mjbe)

Comment: You're lucky your question didn't get downvoted into oblivion! Normally thats what happends when you mention HTML and REGEX in the same sentence....

Comment: Has the question been answered yet?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regex for HTML like @Justinas has already mentioned, in your case, you could try to use some api like jQuery:

```
str = '<![if !supportLists]><span style="mso-list:Ignore">Index<span style="font:7.0pt Times New Roman"> Value &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span><![endif]>'

$(str).text();
```